# Can't install postgresql gem on mac

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, rubygems

I'll be deploying my app on Heroku but wish to develop locally on SQLite. This is the code that I added to my Gemfile.

```
group :development, :test do
    gem 'sqlite3'
end

group :production do
    gem 'postgresql'
end
```

When I do bundle install, this is the error that I get.

```
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /Users/Fulcrum/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/bin/ruby extconf.rb 
checking for pg_config... no
No pg_config... trying anyway. If building fails, please try again with
 --with-pg-config=/path/to/pg_config
checking for libpq-fe.h... no
Can't find the 'libpq-fe.h header
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/Users/Fulcrum/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/bin/ruby
    --with-pg
    --without-pg
    --with-pg-config
    --without-pg-config
    --with-pg_config
    --without-pg_config
    --with-pg-dir
    --without-pg-dir
    --with-pg-include
    --without-pg-include=${pg-dir}/include
    --with-pg-lib
    --without-pg-lib=${pg-dir}/lib

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/Fulcrum/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/pg-0.17.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/Fulcrum/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-13/2.1.0-static/pg-0.17.1/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing pg (0.17.1), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install pg -v '0.17.1'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Comment: look in the log `checking for pg_config... no` that answer  `please try again with
 --with-pg-config=/path/to/pg_config` and use `pg` instead `postgresql`

Comment: @Monk_Code do you mean I have to have pg installed on my local machine for the command to run?

Comment: do you have [brew](http://brew.sh/)? and `postgresql`?

Comment: I've homebrew, but not postgresql installed. The whole point is to do the local development in SqlLite. Since Heroku doesnt support anything other than pg, I have to use that for production.

Comment: ok, try `bundle install --without production`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try bundle install without production:

```
bundle install --without production
```

Answer (score 0):

Install the libpq-dev which is missing.

> `brew install  libpq-dev`

and then do bundle install, this should solve your problem.